# Under what conditions may this function cause memory leakage?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, realloc

```
char *expandspace (char* test) {
    static int i = 0;
    test  = realloc (test, ++i * 100); 
    if(test == NULL) {
        printf("realloc fail");
    }
    return test;
}
```

Under what conditions may this function cause memory leakage? Is there a way to fix it so it works
every time? Thanks.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There's one common but pedantic/artificial remark that many like to do - it goes: don't use the same pointer as `realloc` parameter and result both. Because in case realloc fails, you have lost the pointer to the original memory.

But the question you need to ask is: what causes realloc to fail to begin with? In case realloc fails, it means that the heap is full and your program can't continue doing anything meaningful regardless - you will need to exit. So the remark is nonsensical in practice - leaving your programming running in a undefined world where no reliable heap exists is plain dangerous practice.

Answer (score 4):

If `realloc` fails, then the original memory block is not freed (cf., for example, [realloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) at cppreference.com):

> If there is not enough memory, the old memory block is not freed and
> null pointer is returned.

So in this case, your function will return `NULL`. Depending whether you assign the function result directly to the variable passed to `expandspace`, you may get a leak in such a case:

Problematic:

```
int main() {
   char* test = expandspace(NULL);  // let's assume this is OK...

   // possible leak: if realloc fails, test becomes NULL but the memory it pointed to did not get freed
   // and you lost the pointer, so you cannot free it any more:
   test = expandspace(test);    
}
```

Better:

```
int main() {
   char* test = expandspace(NULL);  // let's assume this is OK...

   char *newTest = expandspace(test);
   if (!newTest) {
      free(test);
      test=NULL;
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: If there isn't enough memory, there is nothing you can do but at best close down the program gracefully. Memory leaks is the least of your concerns when that happens. It's like worrying about a car tire slowly leaking air when the car engine has already exploded into pieces. The question you need to ask is: _what might cause realloc to fail_.

Comment: @Lundin: Maybe, maybe not. Failing to allocate a (probably large) memory block  for specific purposes does not necessarily mean that the heap is "full"; there are (not always but still) meaningful cases to react and continue "normally".

Comment: Alternatively, it could mean that the heap is not full but corrupt - very likely scenario I might add. In which case maintaining a pointer to the previously allocated data isn't likely meaningful either, because it could be corrupt too. No matter if the heap is full or corrupt, your execution environment is toast and you need to terminate.

Comment: @user253751: not always; not if `test` is already NULL before the call.